# Password is url encoded resulting in "The Bluemix credentials you entered don't appear to be valid. Please try again."

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloudant-sdp

I'm trying to create a new warehouse from the Cloudant dashboard, but receive the following error message:

> The Bluemix credentials you entered don't appear to be valid. Please try again.

I had a look at the network traffic and noticed the following url:

```
https://...cloudant.com/_api/v2/partners/dashdb/warehouse/account?
    bluemix_username=...&bluemix_password=...%26...
```

I checked my password and there was an ampersand in it `&` which looks as though it has been url encoded.

Do I need to remove any characters from my password that could get urlencoded to a different value?

Comment: If that app doesn't url-decode the values, then yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the `&` character from my password and I was able to enter my credentials without problem.

I'll leave this Q&A here in case any one else experiences this issue.